# Magento Promotion Rule Coupon Code is not Valid

Tags: magento, rule, invalidation, coupon

I have set a very basic Promotion Shopping Cart Price Rule (Magento ver. 1.6.2.0) just to test that this feature works in my site... but always I receive the same message: "Coupon code is not valid"
I'm going nuts with this... 
These are the parameters I have used:

```
RULE INFORMATION
General Information
Rule Name *: 10% Off
Description: 10% Off
Status *: Active
Websites *: ALL selected
Customer Groups *: ALL selected
Coupon *: Specific Coupon
Coupon Code *: coupon01
Uses per Coupon: 100
Uses per Customer: 1
From Date: 05/04/2013
To Date: 05/04/2015
Priority: 0
Public In RSS Feed: No

CONDITIONS
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Subtotal  equals or greater than  0  

ACTIONS
Update prices using the following information
Apply: Percent of Product Price Discount
Discount Amount *: 10
Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To: 0
Discount Qty Step (Buy X): 0
Apply to Shipping Amount: No
Free Shipping: No
Stop Further Rules Processing: No
Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
None

LABELS
None
```

Please, any tip about what is making this to fail?
Can I track the php error anywhere? When checking the system.log or the exception.log files... no error related to coupons appear at all.

Comment: All looks fine, have you tried it with no conditions?

Comment: Thanks James, yes! no way too...

Comment: Sorry didn't quite catch that, you tried with no conditions and it didn't work also?

Comment: yes, even with no condition set (removing the one I have), the result message is the same: coupon not valid...

Comment: Any idea on how to track a possible PHP error anywhere to detect the cause?